# How to enable timed tests in Open EdX?

Tags: openedx, edx

I have been trying to enable timed tests on Open EdX, but nothing worked so far. Here is what I did:

- I started the server successfully based on the instructions here: https://github.com/edx/devstack#getting-started
- I started a course and add components. Nothing bad yet.
- Then I followed these instructions to config timed tests for the site: https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/enable_timed_exams.html#enable-timed-exams
- In detail, I run `make lms-shell`, then `cd ..` to move 1 level above edx-platform, then change the `ENABLE_SPECIAL_EXAMS` in lms.env.json and cms.env.json to true. The I saved, quitted. Then I did the same with studio: run `make studio-shell`, then `cd ..` to move 1 level above edx-platform, then change the `ENABLE_SPECIAL_EXAMS` in lms.env.json and cms.env.json to true.
- Then I restart lms and studio with `make lms-restart` and `make studio-restart`

However, when I refresh the Studio/CMS, nothing changed and I still couldn't see the Advanced tab to set timing for assignments, although I have change the Enable Timed Exams and Enable Proctored Exams in Advanced Settings to true.

Can someone tell we what I did wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same problem. It should be added inside "FEATURES" which I think is not specified in the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

More information can be found here also https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-ca/en/latest/course_features/timed_exams.html

If you enabled flags in env files, then you just have to enable timed exams in advanced settings.

> Studio -> settings -> Advacned settings

Then set

> "Enable Timed Exams" to true.

Then go to "advanced" in the course sub-module level, and select "**Timed**" as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Isanka. I have done that also, but the Advanced tab in the settings does not show up. I'm wondering if it has something to do with restarting the server? I have run make lms-restart and make studio-restart also, but nothing changes.

Comment: Usually, I use "docker-compose restart lms" and  "docker-compose restart studio" . to restart lms and cms, What's your open edx version?

Comment: I just install the default one, I believe it is the latest one

Comment: I just tried "docker-compose restart lms" and "docker-compose restart studio"  but it stays the same :( I still don't see the advanced tab

Comment: Which shell did you change the env files in? Was it lms-shell or studio-shell? I changed in both of them.

Comment: "ENABLE_SPECIAL_EXAMS": true, in both lms, cms envs